# Area under cardinal interpolation curve

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I want to calculate the area of blue region under the curve. The curve is made by **cardinal interpolation** from the red data points, using D3's `line()`.

[image]

I tried to calculate the area as if it was linear interpolation (along the black lines) but it's not quite the exact number.

Please help me out here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot see a black line. Will that be a linear connection between the red dots?

Comment: Edited, thank you for spotting that out @cars10m

Comment: Tempted to close this as [duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039679/how-can-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-bezier-curve/10045537#10045537).

Comment: get the points along the path, one of the many examples you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/52599555/9938317 so you can interpolate more precise

Comment: @Mark, I don't want to divide the area as subdivisions as in the question you mentioned. That's what I calculate with the black lines :)

Comment: You might be missing the point of the answer I link.  @Phrogz's code sub-divides the curve path and does not use the points the curve was fit from.  In my opinion, it's the cleanest way to get your desired result.  If you really want to implement quickly, though, look at the fourth answer in my [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613616/16363).

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark, I got that now. The smooth of the polygon increases with the exact area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem based on this brilliant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10045537/4505826.
Remember the path must be a closed path, which means it has to end with Z.

When I run the code, the browser keep notifying these errors :

- path.getPointAtLength() is not a function
- path.getTotalLength() is not a function
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElementNS' of undefined

**:::: SOLUTION: Adjust the above code as follows ::::**

```
path.getPointAtLength(d)   ->    path.node().getPointAtLength(d)

path.getTotalLength(d)   ->    path.node().getTotalLength(d)
```

And replace

```
var doc = path.ownerDocument;
var poly = doc.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','polygon');
```

by

```
var poly = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','polygon');
```

as from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25611318/4505826.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the sum of all the trapezoidal partial areas you can use the following formula:

```
Area = ((sum of all y values)- 0.5*((first y value)+(last y value)) * (delta x)
```

Or, JavaSript code:

```
A = (y.reduce((s,v)=>s+v)-.5*(y[0]+y[y.length-1]))*deltax
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For now all the (x,y) points I have are the little red ones. I would like to get the values from the curve but haven't been able to do so.